# Is ‘celebvocate’ gaining currency in English?

Tags: contemporary-english, portmanteau-words

I saw the word, “celebvocate” in “Editor’s Pick” section in today’s (July 14) *Washington Post* which comes under the caption, “When ‘**celebvocates**’ come to D.C.” and followed by the lead copy:

> “Here are a few of the recent visitors seeking to leverage their fame with Congress or the president."

I also saw quite a lot of “celebvocates” in the clips in Google Search, for an example:

> Thursday's **celebvocate**: NFL linebacker Brendon Ayanbadejo Occasion:
>   Announcing his upcoming role as guest editor ... Bob Schieffer on Face
>   the Nation this morning to talk about Jason Collins' coming out and
>   what it means for the future of ...”

I understand “celebvocate” is simply a compound of ‘Celebrity’ and “advocate.” However, Google Ngram shows no incidence of “celebvocates” on its record, and Spellchecker keeps demanding correction of this word, when I’m making proof-check of this post now.

Is “celebvocate” gaining popularity to be perceived as an acceptable word? It seems the word being used predominantly by Washigton Post, which I think is one of influential media in U.S. When did it come into currency?

Comment: Never heard of such a thing in my life.

Comment: Looks like a portmanteau coined by the writer or the writer's clique. For what it's worth, this is a particularly ugly coinage, and feels very forced.

Comment: Jeez, I hope this doesn't catch on.  Last good portmanteau word was "brunch".

Comment: "Is 'celebvocate' gaining currency in English, and if so, how do we stop it?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Washington Post: [The List: what’s out, what’s in as 2011 dawns](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/artsandliving/features/2010/year-in-review/the-list.html)

> **Out** Celebvocacy       **In** Pundraising

Looks like the word goes back to [2009 at the Washington Post](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/reliable-source/celebvocate/)
Other than there, the term doesn't appear to have caught fire at all.